# Search for occurrence of character within a string without using the common lisp library?

Tags: search, string, cl-lib

I need to extract certain information from buffer names, and I'm doing so by extracting substrings based on the position of unique characters within a buffer name string.

So, I currently am doing something like this:

```
(substring (buffer-name) (1+ (search "%" (buffer-name))) (search "&" (buffer-name)))
```

But when I do `flycheck` it complains: "function 'search' from cl pacakge called at runtime".

Is there a good method of search for the first occurrence of a character within a string that I can use that doesn't require calling `(require 'cl-lib)` [or `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))`, which produces the same complaint]? Or would I have to write the string out to a temporary buffer?

Comment: Why don’t you want to use cl-lib, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Dan I'd like ultimately to submit as a MELPA package, and `flycheck` is flagging the use as per above. (Also, I'm curious about what good non-cl ways would be.)

Comment: `search` is in `cl.el`, not `cl-lib.el`.  Does it complain if you use `cl-search` ?

Comment: @phils ah! you're right, it doesn't complain for cl-search.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you ultimately want the characters between `%` and `&` in the buffer name?

You might do this:

```el
(let ((s (buffer-name)))
  (string-match "%\\(.*?\\)&" s)
  (match-string 1 s))
```